# Pseudo elements in Angular5

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, angular5

Why are regular pseudo-classes from `CSS` in Angular5 not working properly? I know that you can mimmic their behaviour using the Angular event handlers like `(click)="function1()"` or `(mouseenter)="function2()"`.

What is the reason we can't use regular `CSS` pseudo-classes in Angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS is working just fine with Angular.

That said, Angular encapsulates the CSS for the current component you're working on (without you having to worry about that). It's a feature that you get with shadow DOM but as not all the browsers supports that, Angular is emulating it by adding properties on your components like that:

```
<div _ngcontent-c6>... your content ...</div>
```

And the original CSS you wrote is then changed by angular to:

```
div[_ngcontent-c0] {
  color: red; // for example
}
```

So if you want to write some CSS that will affect other components and not just the current one, you should set the view encapsulation to none:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [''],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none
})
```

Or, if you have an angular cli project, you can also define the global styles in: `styles.scss` (or `.css`) file which doesn't have any view encapsulation.

See more here: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

(But before turning that feature off, think twice about it as it's really useful)